# Refining search results on multi-word names

Tags: search, user-controls, refiner

I have a basic people search landing page setup with the standard webparts for searching: PeopleSearchBoxEx, PeopleCoreResultsWebpart, etc.

On the page I make use of the [RefineSearchResults](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms499574(v=office.12).aspx) web control to generate a list of titles and titles that can be used to narrow the search.

The template looks like this (there is a similar line for 'Department':

```
<SEARCHWC:RefineSearchResults ID="RefineSearchResults1" runat="server" Title="<%$Resources:sps,RefineByTitle%>" SearchProperty="JobTitle"/>
```

The problem is that department might be a 2+ words name, like "Center for Help". If I click that, the search box becomes `<original search> jobtitle:Center for Help` which gives 0 results. The issue is that the search recognizes only `jobtitle:Center` as a special phrase, whereas `for Help` is viewed as a regular search term.

I tried testing manually with + (no difference) and quoted "", but quotes get removed when I search so they do not help. My question is:

a) Is there a way to do this for multi-word names?

b) How do I implement this in the `RefineSearchResults` control?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use quotes, for example

```
author:"bill jones"
```

Are you sure you used normall quotation marks?